# How to select TOP records in Postgres. Not a similar question

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with three columns (City, Orderid, Total_quantity) and more than 500 rows. I want to fetch the top 50 records according to total_quantity wise. I can do this with rank_number but the twist can be understood with an example.

Example:
Select top 5 (only for example) considering there are only 3 cities.

```
Table1
City Orderid Total_quantity
---------------------------
A      1      90
A      2      80
A      3      70     
B      4      70
B      5      65
B      6      55
C      7      79    
C      8      24

'
'
'
```

If I select the top 5 then the first record should be from city A with max total Quantity, the second record should be from city B with max total quantity, the third record should be from city C with max quantity. **Here is the twist**, the fourth record should be from city A with max quantity and then the final fifth record should be from city B with max total quantity. So the output will be like

Output:

```
Table1
    City Orderid Total_quantity
    ---------------------------
    A      1      90
    B      4      70
    C      7      79
    A      2      80   
    B      5      65
    '
    '
    '
```

Comment: use over window function: SELECT City, Orderid, Total_quantity, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Total_quantity DESC) FROM table, is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select City, Orderid, total_quantity,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY total_quantity desc) as rank_quantity
 from table
 order by rank_quantity,city LIMIT 5;
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hello. The output is not as expected.

Comment: I just editied it can you please check once?

Comment: Thank you. Your query is correct, but with a little change only, replacing rank with rank_numberr gives correct results.